# How to set custom colors in Struts 2 jQuery pie charts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am implementing Struts 2 JQuery pie charts. I don't know how set custom colors for the chart. In backend I  just create map with `key` as `String` and `value` as integer. What attribute I should use for setting custom color or how to set custom color in the pie chart.

**My code is:**

```
<sjc:chart
    id="chartPie2"
    cssStyle="width: 600px; height: 400px;"
    legendShow="false"
    pie="true"
    pieLabel="true"
    pieInnerRadius="0.3"
    pieLabelRadius="0.6"
    pieLabelBackgroundColor="#555"
    pieLabelBackgroundOpacity="0.7"
>
    <s:iterator value="%{pieDataMap}">
        <sjc:chartData
            label="%{key}"
            data="%{value}"
        />
    </s:iterator>
</sjc:chart>
```

**BackEnd:**

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> pieDataMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
   pieDataMap.put("Java", 18);
   pieDataMap.put("C", 17);
   pieDataMap.put("C++", 10);
   pieDataMap.put("PHP", 8);
   pieDataMap.put("(Visual) Basic", 6);
   pieDataMap.put("C#", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<sjc:chartData>` has the `color` attribute which you could set while iterating a map. For this purpose you need to modify the collection to include colors for your series.

```
public class Pie {
  private String name;
  private String color;
  //getters setters and full constructor here    
}
```

then put objects

```
pieDataMap.put(18, new Pie("Java","#990033"));
...
```

after that change the iterator

```
<s:iterator value="%{pieDataMap}">
    <sjc:chartData
        label="%{value.name}"
        data="%{key}"
        color="%{value.color}"
    />
</s:iterator>
```